# PHP delete from database with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to delete an entry in one table of my database. The table name is *book*. But in table *title* use foreign key book.

```
book: id, name
title: id, book_id, title
```

Now I want to delete an entry in *book*. So, I have to delete related entries in *title* table. My code is :

```
$this->db->where(book_id,$deleteid);
$this->db->delete(title);

$this->db->where(id,$deleteid);
$this->db->delete(book);
```

My question is whether the first *where clause* will affect my second *delete clause*?
If it affects the second one, what should I do to avoid this?

Thanks. I am a beginner of PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the first `where` won't affect the second `delete`.

You may find it more intuitive if you rewrite it like this

```
$this->db->delete('title', array('book_id' => $deleteid));
$this->db->delete('book', array('id' => $deleteid));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you are deleting these entries in different tables. Each clauses you have are separate to each other so it will not affect each other.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right , Just delete the foreign key row from title table then delete the primary key row from the book table.