# Delete from Two tables in joined by a relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to delete a row from two tables, Teams & Teams_Members. The `id` in Teams table is a primary key and is a foreign key in teams_members tables known as `team_team_id`.

I tried using this:

```
DELETE `teams`, `teams_members`
FROM `teams`
LEFT JOIN `teams_members`
    ON `teams`.`id` = `teams_members`.`team_team_id`
WHERE `teams`.`id` = 2;
```

But I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`animatordb`.`teams_members`, CONSTRAINT `fk_teams_members_team` FOREIGN KEY (`team_team_id`) REFERENCES `teams` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

How can I achieve my aim, more specifically I want to do this in **PHP**. I am using Codeigniter.

Comment: First `DELETE FROM team_members WHERE team_team_id = 2;` Then `DELETE FROM teams WHERE id = 2;`

Comment: Why don't you simply execute two delete queries, first delete from team_members and then teams table? Basically when you perform select queries, you choice is different type of joins such left join, inner join etc, but for delete you should delete records from individual tables rather than creating joins -- it is no matter php/ raw mysql query

Comment: If you see my edit, I want to do this in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess multi-table syntax is only useful when you're deleting from a single table. To delete from two tables, one-by-one delete is much better. Delete first from table which contains the foreign key & then the other table.

Here's the code I ended up writing,

```
        $this->db->trans_start();

        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM teams_members WHERE team_team_id='$teamid';");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM teams WHERE id='$teamid';");

        $this->db->trans_complete();
```

I am using Codeigniter as I have mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete from team_members first, and then you can delete from the teams table.

If you want to do this in PHP with CodeIgniter, then this link may prove useful

[PHP delete from database with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501633/php-delete-from-database-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 query in `Transactions` like this:

```
//start Transactions
DELETE FROM team_members WHERE team_team_id= 2;
DELETE FROM teams WHERE id = 2;
//commit or rollback.
```

Comment: I guess you can't do `DELETE *`.

Answer (score 0):

First delete the team members then the team in separates deletes.

If you want to ensure that both deletes executes encapsulate your deletes in a transaction

Answer (score 0):

You can try by cascading tables. So,when you delete/update  main table then other relational tables changes automatically.